# loop in bash for parameters that uses multiple sources

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which works like this;

File structure;

- get.sh
- loop.sh
- config/param1.conf
- config/param2.conf

Usage of the main script, `get.sh`;

`./get.sh <param>` i.e `./get.sh param1`, `./get.sh param2`

So when you run the script with specific `param`s it fetches the config files from `config/<param>.conf`

What I'm trying to do is to run this second script, `./loop.sh` so it runs the `./get.sh <param>` for you in a loop using the params inside `config` folder, without `.conf` extensions.

Here's my `loop.sh`;

```
#!/bin/bash

# run the script with the first param you found inside ~/config/ 
# folder without including it's .conf extension,
# wait for 5 seconds and then do the same with the 2nd param you found

for i in $(find ~/config -name '*.conf'); do
  ./get.sh $(basename $i) | cut -d'.' -f 1
  sleep 5
done
```

but this one is just displaying the `param`s inside `config` folder and doing nothing else.
`

Inside of the `config/param1.conf`;

`var=Hello1`

Inside of the `config/param2.conf`;

`var=Hello2`

Inside of the `get.sh`;

```
#!/bin/bash

function testFunction {
  echo "$var"
}

cfg_file=$1

if [ -f "$cfg_file" ]; then
  . "$cfg_file"
  testFunction $1
  exit 1
else
  echo "$1.conf doesn't exist"
  exit 1
fi
```

So after all, when you run the `loop.sh`, the expected behavior should be printing the `Hello1` and `Hello2` strings into shell.

How can I fix this?

Comment: replace `$(find -name \~/config/*.conf)` with `~/config/*.conf`

Comment: now I'm able to start the script, however it's just showing me the params' path and not doing anything.

Comment: In loop.sh, use `./script.sh $(basename $i .conf)`

Comment: that one started the loop.sh, however it's giving me this error after a few seconds; `/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `loop` (using `.sh` extensions for bash scripts is not great practice):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ~/config/*.conf; do
  i_basename=${i##*/}            # change ~/config/foo.conf to just foo.conf
  i_basename=${i_basename%.conf} # change foo.conf to just foo
  ./get "$i_basename"
  sleep 5
done
```

The `${var##prefix}` and `${var%suffix}` syntax is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe); with `##` it removes the longest match from the beginning (so for `*/`, everything up to the last `/`); with `%`, it removes the shortest successful match starting from the end.

---

In `get`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Using POSIX function syntax; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete
testFunction() {
  echo "$var"
}

cfg_file="config/$1.conf"

if [ -f "$cfg_file" ]; then
  . "$cfg_file"
  testFunction
else
  echo "$cfg_file doesn't exist"
  exit 1
fi
```

---

With respect to lack of `.sh` extensions -- UNIX commands don't conventionally *have* extensions (you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`); similarly, when you install a Python module built with setuptools, it doesn't put `.py` extensions on shims it creates in `/usr/local/bin`, even if the libraries those executable shims invoke *do* have such extensions. Moreover, bash and POSIX sh are two different languages: Bash scripts often don't *work correctly* when started with `sh some-bash-only-script.sh` (as unlike `bash`, `sh` isn't guaranteed to support language features like arrays), but the extension implies that they will.

Comment: Thank you, this one just worked! However, I still had to use `./get.sh` because it didn't work the way you tell me. I mean it didn't work without `.sh` extension. Giving me that `./get: No such file or directory` error.

Comment: I'm suggesting to *rename the file* to not have an extension. Extensions (`.bash` for bash-only code, `.sh` for code that works on all POSIX-compliant shells, `.ksh` for ksh-only code, etc) should be used for shell *libraries*, not shell *scripts*; for scripts, the first line (`#!/bin/bash`) specifies the interpreter (and any program, shell script or not, can start them); whereas libraries can only be `source`d from a compatible shell, so including the compatibility in the name is important.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thank you so much. 

Comment: Although Unix itself doesn't generally care about filename suffixes, they're useful for humans. If I look at a directory listing, it's useful to know which files are shell scripts, which are python, etc. Also, tools like IDEs and file managers will use the suffix to assign icons and associate default applications.

Comment: @Barmar, that's true, but using suffixes for executables on UNIX makes for fun times with compatibility: If you rewrite your script that was originally written in shell to be implemented in Python, are you going to force every program that uses it to be updated with the new name? Or are you going to keep a now-misleading name that's out-of-sync with the actual implementation language? (Similarly, the use of `.sh` for scripts that aren't actually compatible with POSIX sh makes for a slow but ongoing stream of bug reports from folks running `sh foo.sh` and wondering why it fails).

Comment: ...one middle ground is to have `/usr/local/libexec/my-program/whatever.bash`, and then symlink to it from `/usr/local/bin/whatever`; that way you get your extension for IDE support, but users don't need to know about it. That said, I'm happy to see more vendors following Apple's lead and caching type metadata in xattrs / resource forks for file-browser responsiveness without needing to read headers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It hardly ever comes up, and in the rare cases when it has, the program isn't called from so many places that it's a problem. We also use things like `php scriptname.php`, so we'd have to change that to `python scriptname.py`.

Answer (score 0):

`-name` expects the parameter to be just a filename, not a whole pathname. You should use the directory as a regular argument to `find`, not as part of `-name`.

```
for i in $(find ~/config -name '*.conf'); do
```

Don't use `basename`, you should pass the entire pathname to `script.sh`.

Then in `script.sh` you should should use `$1` as the whole path to the config file, rather than concatenating it with a directory prefix.

```
cfg_file=$1
```

I don't see any point in this:

```
case $1 in
    $1) cfg=$1 ;;
esac
```

The case will always be true, how can `$1` not match `$1`? Remove that code.

Comment: Thank you, but changing this as you said `cfg_file=$1` is returning this error when I run `./script.sh param1`; `param1.conf doesn't exists.`

Comment: With my `for` loop, `$1` should be the full path, not just a filename. So I don't see how you can be getting that error. Is there something you didn't show that uses `basename` to remove thd directory part of the pathname?

Comment: I'm sorry looks like I've run `loop.sh` inside `loop.sh` instead of `get.sh`. Now we're good, I've edit my question. Final result is; it's just printing the params into the shell now and that's it. It's not running the `script.sh` itself (or running but not doing anything).

Comment: I just found out why it's not doing anything, because `script.sh` isn't working without this code, it's not getting the `.conf` without this; `case $1 in
    $1) cfg=$1 ;;
esac`

Comment: Don't rewrite the question to use the code in the answer. How is anyone supposed to know what I fixed?

Comment: Why does it need that `case` statement? `. "$cfg_file"` doesn't depend on that variable.

Comment: It seems like you're making things much more complicated than they need to be. `find` will return the pathname to the config files, and you just want to use that as is, not remove the directory and then add it back.

Comment: The purpose of `find` is to perform a recursive search through the entire directory hierarchy. Whan you use `basename`, you lose the directory.

Comment: Suggesting `for i in $(find ...)`? That's going to misbehave with filenames that are at all interesting.

Comment: I'm sorry about it. It's my first time using SO. So what I'm at now is that `script.sh` is working alone with params like `./script.sh param1` but only problem is that `loop.sh` isn't running the `script.sh`. With this final version, `./loop.sh` is only displaying the `$i`s but not running the `script.sh` with these `$i`s.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, I just didn't feel like worrying about all that. If the filenames are always of the form `xxx.cfg`, things like whitespace almost certainly aren't an issue.

Comment: Sure; I agree that it's not likely to bite anyone in this use case, but unless that's called out, practices seen in teaching resources get applied outside the initial use cases used to demonstrate them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm having a hard enough time tracking all the changes they're making to the question. Maybe after I figure out what's really going on I'll fix that detail.

Comment: @MarryJane Please put back the original code, if you want to show that it's still not working after trying my fix add that as an addition at the bottom.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry it was my fault. It worked without this `case $1 in
    $1) cfg=$1 ;;
esac` pardon my rookiness. Your fix is working.